# C# Change value on List within class

Tags: c#, list

it may looks some stupid but i stopped coding for a while.
I have a class 'employee' looks like this:

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<task> tasks {get; set;}

        public Employee(string name, List<task> ListTasks)
        {
            Name = name;
       
            tasks = new List<task>();
           //tasks=ListTasks;
            tasks.AddRange(ListTasks);
        }
    }
```

and a class of task:

```
    public class task
    {
        public string Titel { get; set; }
        public int duration { get; set; } = 0;
        public int maxDuration { get; set; }
    }
```

after the creation of 2 (employee-)objects i try to add them to a empList and change the duration of 1 employes (task-)duration, but i always change both, what am i doing wrong ?

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

   
        var taskList = new List<task> { 
            new task
        {
            Titel = "Bumm",
            maxDuration = 4
        }, 
            new task
        {
            Titel = "Kaban",
            maxDuration = 8
        } };


        Employee bla1 = new Employee("werner", taskList);
        Employee bla2 = new Employee("ecki", taskList);

        var empListe = new List<Employee>
        {
            bla1,
            bla2
        };
        // bla2.tasks[1].Dauer = 2;
        empListe[1].tasks[1].duration = 2;
        foreach (var name in empListe)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name.Name);
            foreach (var line in name.tasks)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}/{2}",line.Titel, line.duration, line.maxDuration);
            }
        }
    }
```

i tried differnt ways of initiaon and linking the taskList, I wanted to use a basic tasklist for all employees, but change the value of only eg  one employees tasklist independently of the rest

Comment: Side note: please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code - there is no need for multiple properties in each of the example class, ideally you also include actual/desired output. And please read a C# coding guidelines (any is fine) and follow them *for public code* as one on SO - definitely there is none that call for different casing for properties of a single class.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Employee bla1 = new Employee("werner", taskList);
    Employee bla2 = new Employee("ecki", taskList);
```

Both employees reference the same list. Passing the list does not copy it. The list only exists once. Changing it will be reflected in both employees, which reference the same list.

If you want independent lists, create two separate lists with separate instances as elements:

```
    var taskList1 = new List<task> { 
        new task
    {
        Titel = "Bumm",
        maxDuration = 4
    }, 
        new task
    {
        Titel = "Kaban",
        maxDuration = 8
    } };

    var taskList2 = new List<task> { 
        new task
    {
        Titel = "Bumm",
        maxDuration = 4
    }, 
        new task
    {
        Titel = "Kaban",
        maxDuration = 8
    } };

    Employee bla1 = new Employee("werner", taskList1);
    Employee bla2 = new Employee("ecki", taskList2);
```

Comment: I'd like to use the tasklist as a basic for all created employees but change it independently, is there a possibility?

Comment: @Synav provide a way to copy your `task` instances, then use LINQ to create copies and convert to a new list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is , you are referring to the same list and this will just update the value at the back end in the memory. To solve this, you have to initialize a completely new list with different variables.

for more information, you could refer to the following links :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types

This will help you clear the doubts and will help you to implement your task in the desired way.